# How to implement an inventory system for a game?

Tags: php

How would I go about implementing an inventory system for a game in PHP? I've been trying to figure out a way so that items can be dynamically used instead of just sitting in your inventory, e.g. equipping weapons, using potions, teleporting, etc.

The only solution I can come up with is to store PHP code in the database, and fetch it when the item is used, but that doesn't really seem appropriate. Is there a better way to implement this?

To clarify: It's an mmo browser game, and the inventory of each player needs to persist through the game. Having a class for each item (There may be hundreds of items) seems difficult to maintain if any changes were to be made.

Comment: Can you clarify? If it is meant to be permanent then it should be stored in a DB such as MySQL. If it is temporary to the user then it can still go in the DB or just in a session variable.  You can save arrays in a session variable.

Comment: Sounds like a situation where a normal datastructure and not an DB is needed.  No PHP expert here, but PHP has classes last I heard.  Make a PHP class that represents the inventory and store the items in that.

Comment: You'll need to clarify what type of game, MMO RPG style or a simple 1 player game.  Also does this inventory need to persist to every player as in like the total inventory for the world, or is this just the inventory for 1 player within the world, etc.

Comment: @windfinder - problem is that the web is stateless so it needs to be stored somewhere because it gets wiped on each reload.  A DB could certainly be overkill and the structure is hopefully class-based but it needs to be stored somewhere unless there are no page reloads.

Comment: @Paulo PHP session variables are stored server-side and specific to a browser session. also, PHP classes can be "included". Additionally, session cookies can be used to persist the session.

Comment: Why not have the objects stored in a session?  If it was cookie-based, they could leave and come back, and it would still be there.  Better, that storage would be the onus of the player, rather than you having to deal with the overhead of keeping a database to keep the data.

Comment: Matt: If that were to happen, all their inventory data wouldn't persist across different computers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to implementing a 'baseItem' class as suggested, you may also want to considering developing an interface class for outlining the methods that all items should have. Then, each type of item could implement these methods differently.

For example, all items might need to have an 'equip()' method, but implement it differently based on which kind of items it is. You may not need to create a class for each individual item, but you should probably create classes which are capable of creating unique instances of items based on some sort of data structure you provide (which can be stored in the database).

A really general example might be:

```
class Leather_Armor extends Armor_Base implements Equippable
{
     // these would probably be defined in the base class instead of here
     protected $_itemName;
     protected $_itemDescription;
     protected $_defenseRating;

     public function __construct(params)
     {
         // intialize properties with data from the db
     }


     // the Equippable interface requires us to define this function
     public function equip()
     {
        // call a function from the base class
        $this->recalculateDefenseRating($this->defenseRating)
     }

}
```

You should probably read up on interfaces and abstract classes to fully get the idea.

Also, be aware that this is a really broad, open-ended question than can be approached a thousand different ways. You might want to ask something more specific, or provide concrete examples.

Answer (score 3):

Using PHP you'll need to set up an inventory class, and classes for each of your items - including a "baseItem" class that items inherit from which includes things common to all items (icon?  sound? amount?).

You'll need to store the user's instance of the inventory class in a session variable.  If you want it to persist it should be in a database.

Any page that accesses the inventory will need to reference the file that contains the item and inventory classes.

[This link](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/intro-php-sessions/8) shows setting an object to a session and accessing it across pages.

EDIT: typed too fast and mixed up a couple key terms